# Graphviz how to separate nodes equally (possibly with nodesep)?

Tags: position, equals, distance, graphviz

I am making a graph using dot that splits into 4 parallel rows with links between them (see code below).  I have organised the starting nodes into a subgraph using *rank=same* to ensure they start in line vertically, and then used *edge[weight]* to ensure each row is a straight horizontal line.

Due to the links between the rows, the initial nodes are unequally spaced vertically.  Is there a way of setting them to be equal distance (i.e. increasing the distance between rows C,D,E to match the distance between B,C)?  I have tried using *nodesep* in the subgraph but there is no effect. Any ideas? Thanks

```
graph Example {

rankdir=LR
ordering=out

{ rank=same
b1
c1
d1
e1
}

a1--b1
a1--c1
a1--a2--d1
a2--e1

edge[weight=100]

b1--b2--b3--b4
c1--c2--c3--c4
d1--d2--d3--d4
e1--e2--e3--e4

edge[weight=1]
b1--bc--c3

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a case for **invisible nodes** (and edges...).

Just add some invisible nodes between the rank=same subgraph to force exactly one node between the lines:

```
graph Example {

rankdir=LR
ordering=out

{ rank=same
    b1 [group=b]
    c1 [group=c]
    d1 [group=d]
    e1 [group=e]
    // invisible nodes
    node[style=invis]
    edge[style=invis]
    b1--i1--c1--i2--d1--i3--e1
}
node [group=b]
b1--b2--b3--b4
node [group=c]
c1--c2--c3--c4
node [group=d]
d1--d2--d3--d4
node [group=e]
e1--e2--e3--e4

node[group=""]
a1--b1
a1--c1
a1--a2--d1
a2--e1

b1--bc--c3

}
```

I also used `group`s to suggest straight lines instead of `weight`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are (I think) trying to achieve is the default behavior of graphviz/dot. I think if you remove all "steering" in your graph, you'll get exactly what you need. At least in the below graph, nodes are vertically evenly distributed on each "rank".

```
graph Example {

rankdir=LR
ordering=out

a1--b1
a1--c1
a1--a2--d1
a2--e1
b1--b2--b3--b4
c1--c2--c3--c4
d1--d2--d3--d4
e1--e2--e3--e4
b1--bc--c3
}
```

Comment: Thanks but there are certain layout elements that I want to keep, such as keeping b1,c1,d1,e1 in line vertically, and keeping each row (b,c,d,e) in a straight line. The only change I want to make of the layout is making b1,c1,d1,e1 equal distance from each other.